# .htaccess RewriteRule with AngularJS and ui-router

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I've written my first Angular App using ui-router.  That part seems to have gone okay.  I did it rather quickly so I'm sure there are better ways to do that, but my problem is now that I have it up I'm trying to check all the SEO stuff for Google.

I've read most if not all the docs google has: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/?hl=de

I've set up the /#!/ hashbang, sitemaps and I've created HTML snapshots of every url for the crawler.

I read that Google's 'Fetch as Google' doesn't work with this kind of stuff. (banged my head on that for a while before I found that out) but something is up in my RewriteRule, I think, so pretty sure it wouldn't work anyways.

We have put the site up on a different server to make sure I can get it to work.
http://03ba266.netsolhost.com/

(I adjusted the sitemap to reflect our testing domain)

but it will be http://www.sft.edu once this is right. ( I would love to hear that the fact that we're not using the right domain is the answer, but somehow I don't feel that it is)

I have an .htaccess file in my directory to redirect the bots:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ snapshots/%1.html? [NC,L]
```

hoping that this url: http://03ba266.netsolhost.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/ptp/overview

will look for the snapshot at: http://03ba266.netsolhost.com/snapshots/ptp/overview.html

I feel I must be missing something because when I enter the _escaped_fragment_ url in the browser I get a 404 response.... or, even better in some of my debugging efforts it launches my angular app on the end of that url.  so I "think" it's using my .htaccess file, but I'm not 100%.

I'm hoping that I've missed some little something, but I'm at a lost as to what that is at this point.

Any help with pointers or a direction in which to look would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Casey